# What is a Voluminous Number™?

Tags: pattern, number-property

<sub>*In the spirit of the What is a [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aword+is%3Aquestion)/[Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aphrase+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463), a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aphrase+is%3Aquestion+user%3A463) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aword+is%3Aquestion+user%3A463) puzzles.*</sub>

---

If a number conforms to a special rule, I call it a ***Voluminous Number™***.
Use the examples below to find the rule.

| Voluminous Numbers™ | Not Voluminous Numbers™ |
| --- | --- |
| 62 | 22 |
| 18 | 35 |
| 42 | 97 |
| 25 | 70 |
| 76 | 45 |
| 31 | 17 |

And, if you want to analyze, here is a CSV version:

```
Voluminous Numbers™,Not Voluminous Numbers™
62,22
18,35
42,97
25,70
76,45
31,17
```

The puzzle satisfies the series' inbuilt assumption, that each number can be tested for whether it is a Voluminous Number™ without relying on the other numbers.

**What is the special rule these numbers conform to?**

Comment: nice.  but rot13(vfa'g n 1 abeznyyl evtug whfgvsvrq ba n qvtvgny 7 frtzrag sbag)?

Comment: @SteveV rot13(Nynf, lbh ner evtug! V nffhzrq yrsg nyvtazrag, jubbcf!)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A Voluminous Number™️ is

> a number so that when it’s digits are written digitally and laid over each other, they cover all possible placements for a digital number (like an 8).  Assume a 1 is left aligned for 31 to work. 
>  Picture for reference:
>  [image: digits]